Random sampling of specific observations
I am currently working on a project. Project contains one data frames having V1, V2, V3 and V4. V1 and V2 are unique IDs. V3 and V4 represents disease status.
df
V1   V2   V3 V4
101 201 1 1
102 202 1 1 
103 203 2 NA
104 204 1 2
105 205 1 1
106 206 1 1
107 207 2 NA
108 208 1 1
109 209 2 1
110 210 2 2
111 211  2 NA
112 212  NA 2
113 213  1 1
114 214  1 1
115 215  2 NA

Here, V3 and V4 contains multiple scenarions 1 and 1, 2 and NA, NA and 2 etc. I want to convert 1 and 1 scenario only, means V3 and V4 both have 1. If it is 1 in V3 it should be NA in V4 or vice versa, randomly. Not for 1 and 2 or 2 and 1. But total 1 should be more in V3. I want to use R.
Final dataframe should look like this:
V1   V2   V3 V4
101 201 1 NA
102 202 NA 1 
103 203 2 NA
104 204 1 2
105 205 1 NA
106 206 1 NA
107 207 2 NA
108 208 NA 1
109 209 2 1
110 210 2 2
111 211  2 NA
112 212  NA 2
113 213  1 NA
114 214  1 NA
115 215  2 NA


     


Here's my approach:
You say the total of 1 should be more in V3 than in V4 but you don't say how much.
I'll assume it's 60% - you can change the prop object as required.
prop = 0.6 # 60 % of the new NAs should be in V4

# the rows with 1 and 1 in V3 and V4
both1 <- which(df$V3 == 1 & df$V4 == 1)

# rows where V4 should be set to NA
V4 <- sample(both1, round(length(both1) * prop))
# remainder are rows where V3 shoudl be set to NA
V3 <- both1[!(both1 %in% V4)]


# apply the changes to df
df[V3, "V3"] <- NA
df[V4, "V4"] <- NA


A tidyverse approach
library(dplyr)

set.seed(3)

p = .7

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(V = 
    if_else(V3 == 1 & V4 == 1, 
            sample(list(c(`3`=1,`4`=NA), c(`3`=NA,`4`=1)), 
                   size=1, prob=c(p, 1 - p)), 
            list(c(`3`=V3, `4`=V4))), 
         V3 = NULL, 
         V4 = NULL) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(V, names_sep="")

output
# A tibble: 15 × 4
      V1    V2    V3    V4
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   101   201     1    NA
 2   102   202    NA     1
 3   103   203     2    NA
 4   104   204     1     2
 5   105   205     1    NA
 6   106   206     1    NA
 7   107   207     2    NA
 8   108   208     1    NA
 9   109   209     2     1
10   110   210     2     2
11   111   211     2    NA
12   112   212    NA     2
13   113   213     1    NA
14   114   214     1    NA
15   115   215     2    NA

Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = 101:115, V2 = 201:215, V3 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L), V4 = c(1L, 1L, 
NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

